# How to have custom 404 page for Next.js + GitHub Pages if config is `trailingSlash: true`

Tags: next.js, github-pages, github-actions

I have a static website built with Next.js and currently deployed in GitHub Pages. I already have a custom 404 page created in Next.js with a config `trailingSlash: true` which puts it under this directory `/404/index.html`. In GitHub Pages' documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-custom-404-page-for-your-github-pages-site) and saw that I can use `404.md` which can read permalink, I assume this means the path to my custom 404 page. So I created one in the root folder of my deployment branch.

```
---
permalink: /404/index.html
---
```

But it didn't seem to work. I was wondering if there's something I've assumed or done wrong. Do also note that my GitHub Pages is already under a custom domain. Please suggest if there's another way but still keep the `trailingSlash: true` config because I don't want to show `.html` on the route of my other static pages. Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, instead of using `404.md`, I just added a step in my ci/cd GitHub Actions workflow to move the generated 404 page and rename it to `404.html` which GitHub Pages will understand as my custom 404 page.

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    ...
    steps:
    ...
      - name: Generate static files
        run: yarn export

      - name: Move 404 page to root directory
        run: mv ./out/404/index.html ./out/404.html
```